shit puzzle : Prove your innocence
You are in a crowded train, you want to take a piss. So you go inside a toilet to find somebody shitted badly and the commode has filled up and shit all around. You try to flush but no water.
So you think you will get out due to the unbearable smell. As soon as you get out, a beautiful person stands outside waiting to get inside the toilet.
What do say in a single sentence that is truth/lie but makes the beautiful person convince that you are a good person and you are not responsible for the disaster inside.
PS: I know this can have multiple answers. But the best answer by tomorrow wins ..

try something new ...people downvote and close :(

AmruthA, I'm pretty sure it's not because it's 'new' but because it's obscenity-laden, which doesn't fit with the vibe of the community as a whole...

My negative votes are mostly because this is not a puzzle, so it's off-topic. Also, this is a popularity contest, there is no correct answer, which is a requirement on this site. And yeah, of course it's deliberately disgusting too, but that's a distant third.


 “The train company really needs to employ some cleaners, don’t they?”

